# How does Google news pull news link from different news sites?

Tags: javascript, xml, cross-domain, jsonp

How does google news pull information from almost all the newspapers of world. Is it making a cross domain request to all those news sites individually? As far as I know, I think cross domain feature depends on the server configuration too, then how does google pull news even from a dummy news website which has nothing implemented for cross domain requests. I am also sure that google doesn't have any API for google news.

IN general, how does google news work.

Answer (score 1):

Google copy data (using HTTP clients running on their own computers) from other sites on to their own servers and then present it from there.

Comment: Is this not something violation of privacy? May be I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: No. They can only copy information that they are given access to, and they don't provide any special credentials, so any information they copy is going to be publicly available already.

Comment: Can I use  this (feature) to build something(say an APP)?

Comment: Define "this feature". The ability to write an HTTP client that will fetch content from a site and save it? Yes. Many people have done so. Browser vendors for a start.

Comment: Just find an HTTP library for your programming language of choice.

Comment: @Mike: Use any open source crawler, Apache Nutch for example.